# aspectj cross-thread pointcut

Tags: java, multithreading, aspectj, pointcut

I am new with AspectJ annotation for Java, and I am wondering if it is possible to put pointcut on a cross thread invocation.

Here is the code:

```java
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new Connector().getStart("testtest");
    }
}
```

```java
public class Connector {
    public void getStart(String s1) {
        Handler h = new Handler(s1);
        h.start();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Handler extends Thread {
    String s1;

    public Handler(String s1) {
        this.s1 = s1;
    }

    public void run() {
        new Plain().getValue(s1);   
    }
}
```

```java
public class Plain {
    public void getValue(String s1) {
        System.out.println("Plain getValue: " + s1);
    }
}
```

I would like to have a pointcut that only triggers when `Plain.getValue()` is called by `Connector.getStart()`.

Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a mistake believing that `Plain.getValue(..)` is called by `Connector.getStart(..)` because in a multi-threaded environment it is not. Let me prove it with a little tweak to the `getValue(..)` method, printing a stack trace:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Plain {
    public void getValue(String s1) {
        System.out.println("Plain getValue: " + s1);
        new Exception().printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

By the way, I have moved all your classes to package `de.scrum_master.app` because using the default package is discouraged in Java and also AspectJ does not like it when trying to match pointcuts.

**Console log (multi-threaded):**

```
Plain getValue: testtest
java.lang.Exception
    at de.scrum_master.app.Plain.getValue(Plain.java:4)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Handler.run(Handler.java:9)
```

See? There is no trace of `Connector.getStart(..)` in the log. If we also tweak `getStart(..)` so as to call the thread's `run()` method directly (i.e. not starting a new thread but executing in the same thread) instead of `start()`, the situation changes:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Connector {
    public void getStart(String s1) {
        Handler h = new Handler(s1);
        h.run();
    }
}
```

**Console log (single-threaded):**

```
Plain getValue: testtest
java.lang.Exception
    at de.scrum_master.app.Plain.getValue(Plain.java:4)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Handler.run(Handler.java:9)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Connector.getStart(Connector.java:4)
    at de.scrum_master.app.App.main(App.java:3)
```

In this situation we could use AspectJ's dynamic `cflow()` (control flow) pointcut like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class SingleThreadAspect {
    @Before("execution(* de.scrum_master.app.Plain.getValue(..)) && cflow(execution(* de.scrum_master.app.Connector.getStart(..)))")
    public void interceptControlFlow(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

The advice would be triggered just as you wish. ***But*** for the reason explained at the beginning of my answer `cflow()` does not (and cannot) work across threads because there is no such thing as a direct control flow across threads. Each thread's control flow starts with its `run()` method, no earlier. That is the whole concept of multi-threading.

So if you really want to emulate something like a cross-thread control flow for whatever doubtful reason, you need to do some **manual bookkeeping**.

But first let us revert the tweaked `h.run()` back to the original `h.start()` so as to reinstate the multi-threading situation. Let us also remove the `printStackTrace(..)` line from `Plain.getStart(..)`.

**Solution:**

Disclaimer: I do not like annotation-style @AspectJ syntax, so I am switching over to native syntax. It is much more expressive and we can achieve what we want more easily in terms of ITD (inter-type definition) because

- in native syntax we can just declare an additional instance member variable for a given class while
- in @AspectJ syntax we would have to declare the target class to implement an interface with a default implementation which in turn would carry the member variable for our manual bookkeeping.

Let us modify `App` so as to also start a `Handler` thread directly. This is our negative test case because we do not want to trigger our advice there as the thread is started outside of `Plain.getValue(..)`:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // The aspect should ignore this thread
        new Handler("foo").start();
        // Wait a little while so as not to mess up log output
        Thread.sleep(250);
        new Connector().getStart("testtest");
    }
}
```

**Console log without aspect:**

```
Plain getValue: foo
Plain getValue: testtest
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.*;

public aspect CrossThreadAspect {
    // Declare a new instance member for our bookkeeping
    private boolean Handler.cflowConnectorGetStart = false;

    // If handler thread is started from Connector.getStart(..), set a mark
    before(Handler handler) :
        call(void Handler.start()) &&
        cflow(execution(* Connector.getStart(..))) &&
        target(handler)
    {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + "\n  doing bookkeeping");
        handler.cflowConnectorGetStart = true;
    }

    // If current thread is a marked Handler, log it
    before() :
        execution(* Plain.getValue(..)) &&
        if(Thread.currentThread() instanceof Handler) &&
        if(((Handler) Thread.currentThread()).cflowConnectorGetStart)
    {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + "\n  triggered from parent thread via Connector.getStart(..)");
    }
}
```

**Console log with aspect:**

As you can see, the `Handler` thread started from `App.main(..)` is ignored by the aspect as expected. The `Handler` started from `Connector.getStart(..)` triggers the aspect.

```
Plain getValue: foo
call(void de.scrum_master.app.Handler.start())
  doing bookkeeping
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Plain.getValue(String))
  triggered from parent thread via Connector.getStart(..)
Plain getValue: testtest
```